# Why is this polynomial irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> I want to know why if $a$ is odd, then the polynomial
>   $$ 3x^5 -4x^4+2x^3+x^2+18x+a $$
>   is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I know that if it factors into a polynomial of degree 4 and one of degree 1, it means that it has an integer root, but that is a contradiction since any integer lets an odd value, so it can't be even (0). How can I show that it can't be factorised into a polynomial of degree 2 and another of degree 3?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint 1**

> Consider your polynomial modulo $2$. You get a polynomial over the field $\{ 0, 1\}$ with two elements.

**Hint 2**

> You will only have to check that $0, 1$ are not roots, and that it is not divisible by $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: How the second hint is useful? I see that, but I can't see how it solves the problem.

Comment: You prove that the polynomial modulo $2$ is irreducible. hence the original polynomial is irreducible over the integers.

Comment: But why is true that the polynomial must be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ if it is irreducible modulo 2?

Comment: Because if the polynomial is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$...